# NSOutline/NSTableView source list Lion-style icons

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, osx-lion, nsoutlineview

From the Mac OS X HIG:

> As with the icons that can be used inside toolbar controls, the system applies various effects to sidebar icons. To help you understand how these effects can change the appearance of a sidebar icon, consider the Finder Home icon, shown here in its unprocessed state[...]

So I'm trying to get my NSOutlineView to render a black sidebar icon with the typical new Lion style. I'm using a view-based NSOutlineView. However, I'm unable to find anything in the docs and if I simple set the imageView.image property to the sidebar image, it renders in black. So I figure there must be some sort of opt-in mechanism to get the sidebar to render it properly. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `setTemplate:` (`NSImage`)? That's usually how this kind of image is marked, though I haven't tried this specific case yet.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from using the `setTemplate:` method of `NSImage`, you can just rename your images. This is from the documentation of `imageNamed:`…

> If an application is linked in Mac OS X v10.5 or later, images
>   requested using this method and whose name ends in the word “Template”
>   are automatically marked as template images.